# An unhandled exception was thrown. Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json Version=12.0.0.0 on Azure AppService with .NetCore 3.1

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1

This is an web application which is build on **.net core 3.1**. 
The .Net solution has 4 projects in it and each project's target framework is .net core 3.1. **The start up project is a combination of MVC and Web API**. for example in the action methods of EventController.cs, will call Web API EventAPIontroller using http client. **In local everything works fine** with Visual studio 2019 but **on azure app service it fails only when we try to access swagger or any page where the API calls are made using http client**. It always fails with the below error:

An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

> 2020-06-10T17:14:20.675781424Z: [INFO] System.IO.FileLoadException:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (0x80131040) 2020-06-10T17:14:20.675794424Z: [INFO] File name:
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' 2020-06-10T17:14:20.675799325Z:
>   [INFO] at BEMS.Controllers.EventController.Events()
>   2020-06-10T17:14:20.675803025Z: [INFO] at lambda_method(Closure ,
>   Object , Object[] ) 2020-06-10T17:14:20.675806725Z: [INFO] at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters) 2020-06-10T17:14:20.675810625Z: [INFO]*

---

BEMS.csproj file :

```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
        <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <DocumentationFile></DocumentationFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Remove="Controllers\EventsController.cs" />
      <Compile Remove="Helpers\PropertyIgnoreHelper.cs" />
      <Compile Remove="ViewModel\Events.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Remove="Views\Event\EventDetails.cshtml" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="3.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" Version="3.0.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.0.0">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core" Version="3.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="4.7.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\BEMS.AzureDataLayer\BEMS.AzureDataLayer.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\BEMS.Services\BEMS.Services.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\BEMS.Models\BEMS.Models.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Views\Admin\" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

---

BEMS.Services.csproj :

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" Version="3.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BEMS.DataLayer\BEMS.DataLayer.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BEMS.Models\BEMS.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

---

BEMS.Modals.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="ViewModel\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="ViewModel\**" />
    <None Remove="ViewModel\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

BEMS.DataLayer.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
        <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
        <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TEMS.Models\TEMS.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[This is the error I can see in azure app service log stream whenever I try to access Web API :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wazqg.png)

Comment: I am assuming you are doing API calls on your **BEMS.Services** layer. In **BEMS.Services.csproj** file I didn't see reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` package. Could you please, explicitly add `Newtonsoft.Json` package with the version **12.0.3** via Nuget package manager to your **BEMS.Services.csproj**, then deploy the service with your new artifacts. It might solve your issue.

Comment: Can the program run successfully locally?